# "Add native support" missing for Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

Following NDK Getting Started tutorial I installed Eclipse, SDK and NDK. I also set up correct path to NDK in  Window > Preferences > Android > NDK as described here: http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/setup.html#configure

Then in the "Verification" section of this document I am asked to load "hello-jni" project, right click it and select Android Tools > Add Native Support.

But there's just no such option! How do I diagnose this? Is there something wrong with NDK?
I am using Ubuntu 14.04, NDK is added to path. App runs OK when I press "Run" in Eclipse, but displays lots of syntax errors in C++ code like:

```
Method 'NewStringUTF' could not be resolved hello-jni.c /HelloJni/jni   line 62 Semantic Error
Type 'JNIEnv' could not be resolved hello-jni.c /HelloJni/jni   line 27 Semantic Error
Type 'jobject' could not be resolved    hello-jni.c /HelloJni/jni   line 28 Semantic Error
Type 'jstring' could not be resolved    hello-jni.c /HelloJni/jni   line 26 Semantic Error
```

Comment: BTW, I solved my problem by installing latest versions of NDK and Eclipse, now it works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install android studio, and use the NDK inside that. 
It's about (and I'm not exaggerating) 500000000000000000 times better. Although right now its just a preview, it will be fully released soon (I hope)

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yeah, I know that Android Studio is much better (http://www.ihateeclipse.com/). However my current task is to profile Android NDK application. Seems like Android Studio does not yet support any NDK profiling tools and the existing ones are easier to setup with Eclipse. I may be mistaken though, please tell if you know good tools for C++ profiling that are easy to setup with Studio.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't :( Sorry mate.